# parse.com - How to set CLP from code?

Tags: parse-platform, clp

I have a function on Cloud Code that generates dynamic classes. And these classes may not be accessible outside the Cloud Code(without the MasterKey).

So my question is... how to configure the CLP from Cloud Code to these new classes?

I already have tried to set ACL to an object, but I need to configure for entire class.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not way at the moment to set the Class Level Permissions via an code. I have not seen this even in their [Schema API](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#schemas)